# How to set up a git server with SSH access

Tags: git, setup

I have a server running Ubuntu where I installed a SVN server and integrated it with Apache.
My users access their repository via HTTPS and I am able to configure which repo each user can access.

I would like to set up also a git server with the following features:

- Access via SSH keys.
- Possibility of selecting which repositories each user can access.
- (Optional) web-interface for creating new repos.

I googled a little bit but I wasn't able to find a good tutorial that provides me all these features. In particular I didn't find how to set up the user rights.

How can I setup the git server?

Comment: I recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite Then, optionally these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627643/setting-up-git-server-with-web-interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249088/how-to-set-up-private-git-server-on-linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620439/how-to-setup-public-git-repositories

Answer (score 1):

I use gitolite for a private git server, it is easy to configure and fulfills your first two requirements. Source code and documentation for gitolite can be found here https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

As far as a web interface for creating new repos goes, you might be interested in learning more about GitlabHQ which is an open-source web application that aims to emulate github. This would provide you with a graphical interface to create new repos, change permissions, add SSH keys etc. GitlabHQ uses gitolite as their git-server as well. Documentation, source-code, and installation instructions can be found here http://gitlabhq.com/.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Git Drive, https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/git-drive/id1215974700?ls=1&mt=8, You would be able to setup a Git server in minutes.

> Git Drive is a system specially made for iOS, enabling Git version control software to be operated on mobile devices. With Git Drive, your iOS device becomes a perfectly functioning Git version control server in the palm of your hand. The Git Smart transfer protocol is fully implemented on this server, including transmission stability and speed.
>
> Authorization of other users for repository access is under your complete control, and shallow updates and cloning operations for the repository are also supported.
>
> Besides acting as a perfectly functioning Git version control server, the Git Drive software also acts as a powerful Git client, offering enough functionality for you to effectively manage changes to repositories and check up on any documents directly from the app.
>
> Git Drive use iCloud as the backup storage for Git Drive; through iCloud, it can sync any repository updates across all devices.

Features:

- Power Git Server supports Git Smart transfer protocol; supports access by 5-10 users at a time (using iPad will increase concurrent user accessibility).
- Repository management; every repository update operation will be controlled by transaction; if the operation is interrupted, all data will be immediately rolled back, or automatically rolled back when Git Drive is re-started.
- iCloud repository syncing; no need to worry about data loss, because all repositories are backed up on the cloud.
- Graphical commit record; all branches are available at a glance.
- High-speed syntax coloring engine; supports syntax coloring for over 100 programming languages; will be updated periodically.

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for - he wants to have his server on Ubuntu device.